# Enforce return type of function to be the inherited generic class and not the base non-generic one

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, inheritance

I have a base class `Outcome` which is inherited by a generic class `Outcome(Of T)`. Both classes here have their own use cases, so sometimes you would want to use a non-generic `Outcome` and other times the generic one.

I'm trying to create a function with an explicit return type of the inherited generic class `Outcome(Of T)`, specifically `Outcome(Of String)`. However, it seems like I can simply return an object of the non-generic type `Outcome` and the compiler does not throw any errors.

How do I enforce that the return type here has to be an instance of `Outcome(Of String)`?

### Minimal Code

##### `Outcome`

```vb
Public Class Outcome
    Public IsSuccessful As Boolean
    Public IsException As Boolean
    Public Message As String

    Public Sub New()
        Me.IsSuccessful = True
        Me.IsException = False
        Me.Message = ""
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(isSuccessful As Boolean, isException As Boolean, message As String)
        Me.IsSuccessful = isSuccessful
        Me.IsException = isException
        Me.Message = message
    End Sub
End Class
```

##### `Outcome(Of T)`

```vb
Public Class Outcome(Of T)
    Inherits Outcome

    Public Result As T

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Me.Result = Nothing
    End Sub
    
    Public Sub New(isSuccessful As Boolean, isException As Boolean, message As String, result As T)
        MyBase.New(isSuccessful, isException, message)
        Me.Result = result
    End Sub
End Class
```

##### Function

```vb
'' This method should throw a compilation error
Private Function Test() As Outcome(Of String)
    Return New Outcome()
End Function
```

Comment: You likely have [Option Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) Off that directs the compiler to insert the type conversion from `Outcome` to `Outcome(Of String)`

Comment: Adding `Option Strict On` to the module does produce a compiler error.

Comment: You're right, Option Strict was Off for this project. I'm going to try turn it on and clean up the huge amount of errors here but in the meantime, is there a way to check for such implicit type conversions without Option Strict?

Comment: Is there a way to prevent something without using the tool designed to prevent it? Why would there be? You can turn `Option Strict On` at the file level so, if turning it `On` at the project level generates an overwhelming number of compilation errors then you can do it one file at a time to clean the code up slowly and then do it at the project level when you're done or nearly done. Note that you should turn `Option Strict On` in the VS options so that it's `On` by default for all future projects.

Comment: If you want to detect implicit narrowing conversions and late binding in your code without "fixing" the issues then turn `Option Strict On` temporarily, then turn it `Off` again.

Comment: There are some individual build options that pick up some (but not all) of the things that are encapsulated in `Option Strict On`.  If you go to the project properties and select the "Compile" ply, under "Warning configurations" you can e.g. set "Implicit conversion" to "Error".  This would address that particular subset of `Option Strict On`.  (But if you're getting a lot of errors, this is likely to be one of the culprits, so it may not be that helpful to turn on just the one error.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to figure out why the derived return type wasn't enforced. I'll outline the solutions given in order of good practice and then write my personal workaround for the issue.

### Option Strict

Turning Option Strict On is the simplest way to enforce this check and also helps catch other bad practices like Late Binding to `Object` type.

You can find it in the Project Properties under the Compile tab
[image]

### Changing the Warning configuration for Implicit conversion

Another way is to change the warning configuration for Implicit conversion to Error. This is useful if get a lot of errors with `Option Strict On` but still want to cover the implicit conversions without using `Option Strict`

You can also find this in Project Properties under the Compile tab
[image]

### Using Composition instead of Inheritance

Unfortunately, neither of the compile options were a viable strategy for me because I was dealing with a huge legacy codebase (think in the order of tens of thousands of errors)

Therefore I went with the workaround of `Outcome(Of T)` having `Outcome` as a composite property instead of inheriting from it:

##### `Outcome`

```vb
Public Class Outcome
    Public IsSuccessful As Boolean
    Public IsException As Boolean
    Public Message As String

    Public Sub New()
        Me.IsSuccessful = True
        Me.IsException = False
        Me.Message = ""
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(isSuccessful As Boolean, isException As Boolean, message As String)
        Me.IsSuccessful = isSuccessful
        Me.IsException = isException
        Me.Message = message
    End Sub
End Class
```

##### `Outcome(Of T)`

```vb
Public Class Outcome(Of T)
    '' Composite field
    Private _InnerOutcome As Outcome

    Public Result As T

    Public Property IsSuccessful As Boolean
        Get
            Return _InnerOutcome.IsSuccessful
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _InnerOutcome.IsSuccessful = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property IsException As Boolean
        Get
            Return _InnerOutcome.IsException
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _InnerOutcome.IsException = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Message As String
        Get
            Return _InnerOutcome.Message
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _InnerOutcome.Message = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        _InnerOutcome = New Outcome()
        Me.Result = Nothing
    End Sub
    
    Public Sub New(isSuccessful As Boolean, isException As Boolean, message As String, result As T)
        _InnerOutcome = New Outcome(isSuccessful, isException, message)
        Me.Result = result
    End Sub
End Class
```

##### Function

```vb
'' Now this method does throw a compilation error
Private Function Test() As Outcome(Of String)
    Return New Outcome()
End Function
```

It's not perfect, but it helps enforce my constraint without needing to fix thousands and thousands of other errors.